# How to get the high score leaderboard Rock Band?

Tags: rock-band-3

In Rock Band 3 song "Love struck baby", how do I get a higher score for the "improvise (solo)" part? I kept the highest multiplier during the entire song and played 100% flawless. I tried 3 different things during the solo part to make the best score (like adding double base) but the score stayed the same! I want to know how the number one of the world did it.

[image]

Is it to play as many notes as possible, to play on many different pads, or is it to play exactly the same as the original part of the song? Or something else.

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade, and congratulations on your score. I left your first image up in good faith, it is not relevant to the question, but I see no harm. Adding in a second just to brag is overdoing it just a little.  We try to be a bit more "straight to the point" on here, with the motto of 'just questions and answers, no chit chat'. Forums are a lot better for chit chat and showing off - and equally, Arqade is a lot better at getting the answers without all the B*S :)

Comment: Thanks. I added an other (better) picture of a better position in the world leaderboard but the question stays the same.

Comment: the second picture is just because in the first pic it is not really visible

Comment: and with better picture i mean a song that the multiplier was on maximum during the entire song. The former picture was not maximized on the multiplier so this picture is obviously better in this sence

Comment: by the way they did not (yet) put me in the list on the 3rd spot. Why is this? They keep showing my older score. I've done it today. video link is coming up it is uploading.

Comment: I've removed your video and one picture, as it's borderline spam, and kinda irrelevant to answering the question.  Yes, you did good.  Great.  No need to brag about it.